# Include SKU in cart price rule that is being excluded by another condition

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to create the following cart price rule:

- Exclude all products with certain tax-class
- Include certain SKUs that have that tax-class

I know, sounds weird. But product management wants it that way.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

[image: this rule doesn't work]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the rule in a way so it reads something like this:

```
If ANY of these conditions are TRUE:
  If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
    rules
  If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:
    other rules
```

Wrapping rules like this should allow you to check for any of the acceptable condition combinations.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks for your help!